# KDE Plasma 5.7 tray icons

Tags: kde5

I've updated my plasma version to 5.7 and some of tray icons (like Skype or google chrome) are missing. How to fix it?

Tray screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is it ubuntu? How did you get an update? Did you build the sources by yorself? I ask because I cannot find ppa but want to update.

Comment: Actually, it is not Ubuntu but a distribution of it, KDE Neon.

Comment: Exactly as I thought. Kubuntu backports ppa hasn't been updated at the moment when I asked yet, but now plasma 5.7.1 is there. Anyway, thanks for the reply. Cheers!

Comment: @Grief your comment is confusing. 5.7.1 is not available in the PPA.

Comment: @RolandiXor Now even 5.7.2 is available and it almost free of bug (I only marked konsole, konsole-data and yakuake as 'hold'): https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when upgraded from 5.6 to 5.7, found a fix in this post:

https://plus.google.com/+TimGoodwin/posts/QubDt1Loky7

> The icon issue can be fixed by opening terminal and typing:
>   `sudo apt remove sni-qt sni-qt:i386 plasma-systray-legacy`
>   and restarting the apps.

Removing "sni-qt", "sni-qt:i386", "plasma-systray-legacy" solved the issue.

Comment: How did you upgrade?